# Who first proposed the idea of quantum computing using qubits?

Tags: history

As I understand it, the field of quantum mechanics was started in the early 20th century when Max Planck solved the black-body radiation problem. But I don't know when the idea of computers using quantum effects spread out.

What is the earliest source that proposes the idea of quantum computers using qubits?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to Wikipedia of [Timeline of quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_quantum_computing), here are the main events:

- 1960

  > [Stephen Wiesner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Wiesner) invents [conjugate coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_coding).
- 1968

  A quantum computer with spins as quantum bits was also formulated for use as a quantum spacetime in 1968.

  <sup>Finkelstein, David (1968). "Space-Time Structure in High Energy Interactions". In Gudehus, T.; Kaiser, G. Fundamental Interactions at High Energy. New York: Gordon & Breach.</sup>
- 1973

  > [Alexander Holevo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Holevo) publishes a paper showing that n qubits cannot carry more than n classical bits of information (see: ["Holevo's theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem)/"Holevo's bound").
  >
  > [Charles H. Bennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Bennett_(computer_scientist)) shows that computation can be done reversibly.
- 1976

  > Polish mathematical physicist [Roman Stanisław Ingarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Stanis%C5%82aw_Ingarden) publishes a seminal paper entitled "Quantum Information Theory" in Reports on Mathematical Physics, vol. 10, 43–72, 1976.
- 1980

  > Paul Benioff described quantum mechanical Hamiltonian models of computers
  >
  > [Yuri Manin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_I._Manin) proposed an idea of quantum computing
- 1981

  > Richard Feynman in his talk [...], observed that it appeared to be impossible in general to simulate an evolution of a quantum system on a classical computer in an efficient way. He proposed a basic model for a quantum computer that would be capable of such simulations
- 1982

  > Paul Benioff proposes the first recognisable theoretical framework for a quantum computer.

So in general, the field of quantum computing was initiated by the work of [Paul Benioff](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Benioff) <sup>[study](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01011339)</sup> and [Yuri Manin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Manin) in 1980, [Richard Feynman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) in 1982 <sup>[study](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02650179)</sup>, and [David Deutsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Deutsch) in 1985. Source: [Quantum computing at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing).

Comment: I think Wiesner developed conjugate coding in the late 1960’s, not in the early 60’s…

Answer (score 7):

Around 1960-1973 the idea was beginning to form, but the field really started spreading in the 1980s.

One of the biggest pioneers was Richard P. Feynman. **He proposed a model of a quantum computer in his [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_Plenty_of_Room_at_the_Bottom)**. From that talk, many other scientists pushed the field further (Toffoli created one of the first quantum gates; Shor, at Bell Labs, created one of the first quantum algorithms etc.)

The field has been changing and evolving rapidly throughout 1980-2000, and keeps evolving. But the initial "spark" was made by Richard Feynman. I don't know if he thought of qubits, but his main interest in quantum computing was for simulating quantum physics and systems.

Comment: The Wikipedia link presently (2021) seems to dismiss the importance of Feynman's 1959 lecture - I think Feynman's work in the early '80s may have been more impactful on the field...  I also don't think Toffoli knew that he was creating a **quantum** gate *per se* but was more interested in **reversible** gates (which are subsets of quantum gates).  I think it was Bennett and others who drew the connection between reversibility and quantum computing, although it's true that Feynman may have contributed the initial spark in the 80's.